Treegraph chart with Highcharter
I'm trying to reproduce this Highcharts Phylogenetic language tree in R: link 1 and link 2.
The first step I took was to check if I had all the necessary modules. It turned out that highcharteR didn't include the  modules/treegraph.js file. So, I manually downloaded it and placed it in the directory R\win-library\4.0\highcharter\htmlwidgets\lib\highcharts\modules
I then tried to convert the JS Highchart code from jsfiddle into R code:
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)


series = list(
  list(
    type = "treegraph",
    keys = c('id', 'parent', 'link.type'),
    clip =  FALSE,
    data = list(
      list(NA, 'Proto Indo-European'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Balto-Slavic'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Germanic'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Celtic'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Italic'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Hellenic'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Anatolian'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Indo-Iranian'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Tocharian'),
      list('Indo-Iranian', 'Dardic'),
      list('Indo-Iranian', 'Indic'),
      list('Indo-Iranian', 'Iranian'),
      list('Iranian', 'Old Persian'),
      list('Old Persian', 'Middle Persian'),
      list('Indic', 'Sanskrit'),
      list('Italic', 'Osco-Umbrian'),
      list('Italic', 'Latino-Faliscan'),
      list('Latino-Faliscan', 'Latin'),
      list('Celtic', 'Brythonic'),
      list('Celtic', 'Goidelic'),
      list('Germanic', 'North Germanic'),
      list('Germanic', 'West Germanic'),
      list('Germanic', 'East Germanic'),
      list('North Germanic', 'Old Norse'),
      list('North Germanic', 'Old Swedish'),
      list('North Germanic', 'Old Danish'),
      list('West Germanic', 'Old English'),
      list('West Germanic', 'Old Frisian'),
      list('West Germanic', 'Old Dutch'),
      list('West Germanic', 'Old Low German'),
      list('West Germanic', 'Old High German'),
      list('Old Norse', 'Old Icelandic'),
      list('Old Norse', 'Old Norwegian'),
      list('Old Swedish', 'Middle Swedish'),
      list('Old Danish', 'Middle Danish'),
      list('Old English', 'Middle English'),
      list('Old Dutch', 'Middle Dutch'),
      list('Old Low German', 'Middle Low German'),
      list('Old High German', 'Middle High German'),
      list('Balto-Slavic', 'Baltic'),
      list('Balto-Slavic', 'Slavic'),
      list('Slavic', 'East Slavic'),
      list('Slavic', 'West Slavic'),
      list('Slavic', 'South Slavic'),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Phrygian', 6),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Armenian', 6),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Albanian', 6),
      list('Proto Indo-European', 'Thracian', 6),
      list('Tocharian', 'Tocharian A', 6),
      list('Tocharian', 'Tocharian B', 6),
      list('Anatolian', 'Hittite', 6),
      list('Anatolian', 'Palaic', 6),
      list('Anatolian', 'Luwic', 6),
      list('Anatolian', 'Lydian', 6),
      list('Iranian', 'Balochi', 6),
      list('Iranian', 'Kurdish', 6),
      list('Iranian', 'Pashto', 6),
      list('Iranian', 'Sogdian', 6),
      list('Old Persian', 'Pahlavi', 6),
      list('Middle Persian', 'Persian', 6),
      list('Hellenic', 'Greek', 6),
      list('Dardic', 'Dard', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Sindhi', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Romani', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Urdu', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Hindi', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Bihari', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Assamese', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Bengali', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Marathi', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Gujarati', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Punjabi', 6),
      list('Sanskrit', 'Sinhalese', 6),
      list('Osco-Umbrian', 'Umbrian', 6),
      list('Osco-Umbrian', 'Oscan', 6),
      list('Latino-Faliscan', 'Faliscan', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Portugese', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Spanish', 6),
      list('Latin', 'French', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Romanian', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Italian', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Catalan', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Franco-Provençal', 6),
      list('Latin', 'Rhaeto-Romance', 6),
      list('Brythonic', 'Welsh', 6),
      list('Brythonic', 'Breton', 6),
      list('Brythonic', 'Cornish', 6),
      list('Brythonic', 'Cuymbric', 6),
      list('Goidelic', 'Modern Irish', 6),
      list('Goidelic', 'Scottish Gaelic', 6),
      list('Goidelic', 'Manx', 6),
      list('East Germanic', 'Gothic', 6),
      list('Middle Low German', 'Low German', 6),
      list('Middle High German', '(High) German', 6),
      list('Middle High German', 'Yiddish', 6),
      list('Middle English', 'English', 6),
      list('Middle Dutch', 'Hollandic', 6),
      list('Middle Dutch', 'Flemish', 6),
      list('Middle Dutch', 'Dutch', 6),
      list('Middle Dutch', 'Limburgish', 6),
      list('Middle Dutch', 'Brabantian', 6),
      list('Middle Dutch', 'Rhinelandic', 6),
      list('Old Frisian', 'Frisian', 6),
      list('Middle Danish', 'Danish', 6),
      list('Middle Swedish', 'Swedish', 6),
      list('Old Norwegian', 'Norwegian', 6),
      list('Old Norse', 'Faroese', 6),
      list('Old Icelandic', 'Icelandic', 6),
      list('Baltic', 'Old Prussian', 6),
      list('Baltic', 'Lithuanian', 6),
      list('Baltic', 'Latvian', 6),
      list('West Slavic', 'Polish', 6),
      list('West Slavic', 'Slovak', 6),
      list('West Slavic', 'Czech', 6),
      list('West Slavic', 'Wendish', 6),
      list('East Slavic', 'Bulgarian', 6),
      list('East Slavic', 'Old Church Slavonic', 6),
      list('East Slavic', 'Macedonian', 6),
      list('East Slavic', 'Serbo-Croatian', 6),
      list('East Slavic', 'Slovene', 6),
      list('South Slavic', 'Russian', 6),
      list('South Slavic', 'Ukrainian', 6),
      list('South Slavic', 'Belarusian', 6),
      list('South Slavic', 'Rusyn', 6)
    ),
    marker = list(
      symbol = "circle",
      radius = 6,
      fillcolor = "#ffffff",
      lineWidth = 3
    ),
    dataLabels = list(
      align = "left",
      style = list(color = "#000000", whiteSpace = 'nowrap')
    ),
    levels = list(
      list(level = 1,
           levelIsConstant =  FALSE),
      list(level = 2,
           colorByPoint =  TRUE),
      list(
        level = 3,
        colorVariation = list(key = 'brightness',
                              to = -0.5)
      ),
      list(
        level = 4,
        colorVariation = list(key = 'brightness',
                              to = 0.5)
      ),
      list(
        level = 6,
        dataLabels = list(x = 10),
        marker = list(radius = 4)
      )
    )
    
  )
)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(backgroundColor = "white") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(series)

but this code generate a blank graph...

Could you please help me in identifying my mistake and providing a solution?

I'm afraid it won't be possible, since the official Highcharter distribution uses Highcharts v9.3.1, and the treegraph series has been introduced since Highcharts > v11. You can always try to swap Highcharts files inside of the Highcharter directories to v11, but there's no guarantee that it will work properly.
References:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v11.0.0
https://jkunst.com/highcharter/news/index.html#highcharter-094

Thank you for the informations... HighchateR actually uses uses HighchartsJS 10.2.0....
I've tried to update the files but as expected is not that easy to update a package....
